# VBA Automatically add autocorrection entries in word from an excel list

Tags: vba, excel, autocomplete, ms-word, shortcut

I am trying to add a huge amount of autocorrect entries into WORD loading the data of an excel file/sheet.
This is actually not with Autocorrections purposes but in order to use shortcuts to introduce complete paragraphs to write much faster.

First I tried:

```
Sub autocorrectlist() 
'TRYING OUT IF using variables works for a new autocorrect entry.
Dim myString1 As String
Dim myString2 As String
myString1 = "BBBB"
myString2 = "BBBB works works works"
AutoCorrect.Entries.Add Name:=myString1, Value:=myString2
```

This worked. when writing BBBB in Word get substitute by the other expression.
lets try to read values from the excel file.
It is a big long here the code but it consist basically in open an excel file and read the entries of an excel sheet, one column being the entries for the so called shortcut (the text that has to be substitute) and the other one the substituting text)

```
'lets create a huge list of modifiers
Dim i As Integer 'counter

'Read Excel File Megaclause
Dim oXL As Excel.Application
Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim oRng As Excel.range
Dim ExcelWasNotRunning As Boolean
Dim WorkbookToWorkOn As String

'specify the workbook to work on
WorkbookToWorkOn = "C:\Users\JF30443\Desktop\WORK\EXCEL\megaclause7.xlsm"

'If Excel is running, get a handle on it; otherwise start a new instance of Excel
On Error Resume Next
Set oXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

If Err Then
     ExcelWasNotRunning = True
     Set oXL = New Excel.Application
End If

On Error GoTo Err_Handler
oXL.Visible = True

'Open the workbook
 Set oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=WorkbookToWorkOn)

'Process each of the spreadsheets in the workbook
Dim mySht As Worksheet
Set mySht = oWB.Worksheets("sc6")
Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = mySht.Cells(mySht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Dim myName As String
Dim myAuto As String

'reading the values from the sheet
For i = 1 To lastRow
myName = mySht.Cells(i, 1).Value
myAuto = mySht.Cells(i, 2).Value
If myName <> "" And myAuto <> "" Then
    MsgBox ("nr:" & i & "myName:" & myName & "//myauto:" & myAuto)
    'note here: actually it read correctly the two first values of the SC6 sheet
    'Since the values displayed by the msgbox are correct
    'the following line gives an error
    Application.AutoCorrect.Entries.Add Name:=myName, Value:=myAuto
    'the error being:
    'AutoCorrect cannot replace text which contains a space character.
End If
Next


If ExcelWasNotRunning Then
oXL.Quit
End If

'Make sure you release object references.
Set oRng = Nothing
Set oSheet = Nothing
Set oWB = Nothing
Set oXL = Nothing

'quit
Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
MsgBox WorkbookToWorkOn & " caused a problem. " & Err.Description, vbCritical, _
       "Error: " & Err.Number
 If ExcelWasNotRunning Then
   oXL.Quit
End If

End Sub
```

As stated in the code between lines the code reads the sheet because the msgbox displays correctly the two first values of the sheet called "SC3" but inmediatly after it gives error.
I copied partially this code from internet, but the one I thought would be the most difficult part (reading from word in excel) works, and then I can not add the entry.

What is even more strange is that the first part of the code above pasted (the one with "BBBB") works, which is basically the same approach as in the loop.

I searched for info in the net but I did not find anything relevant relating to taht error.

Help is welcome

Thanks.

Comment: The error message says it all: "'AutoCorrect cannot replace text which contains a space character". That sounds as if myName contains a space (BBBBBB did not). The terms used for AutoCorrect may not contain spaces. If you're not seeing a space, check the beginning and the end of the entry. NOTE: Building Blocks (AutoText) might be the better approach than AutoCorrect for storing things you want to insert quickly. You can store formatting, entire paragraphs, graphics... Type in the identifier then press F3.

Comment: Sure, omg. I had the trim() function in the wrong place. Unluckly in any case the autocorrection subtitution text can not be larger than 255 characteres...

Comment: Then you should definitely look at the Building Blocks/AutoText approach. That has no size limit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an initial space in the names of the sheet